# MVC 6 app building, but erroring in view after moving identity to new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Using the default Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC6 app and to truly build out with SOC principles, I moved the ApplicationUser and the DbContext to seperate class library projects. 
[image: Solution Folder]
The solution builds, but when the application is run it generates the following error.

I have now tried this on numerous new projects, moving either just ApplicationUser to its own Classes library or moving both ApplicationUser to a classes library and ApplicationDbContext and its migrations to a separate class library project. (As shown in the project tree above) and whenever I try to run the app I get this error. I have checked every single file in the project. There are no coding errors anywhere in the solution relating to UserManager, SignInManager, ApplicationUser etc)

[image]

What little I've found on this topic is not helping me. One solution says eliminate the global.json file. My solution doesn't have one.

The Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web seems old, last updated 15 months ago. Is it still used?  I know the problem lies with moving the Identity items to separate projects but I'm at a loss to see why this view generation is erring with no build errors.

I had originally selected the current answer (I have now rescinded it) as the answer because in going over every file in THAT specific project, I had fixed the error (unknowingly) so I gave him some credit for making me look at everything even though VS automatically adds those using statements to resolve the errors when you move the ApplicationUser file.

But now this is happening with every test solution I am trying, move the ApplicationUser and you can't get the starting page of the app to open.

The problem was in the partial view _LoginPartial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a reference to your `Application.UI` project referencing `Application.Domain`. Without specifying it explicitly your application won't build.

You'll also need to add a `@using Application.Domain;` to any file where your using `ApplicationUser`

Comment: @phuzi...Application.UI IS referencing Application.Domain and the appropriate using statements are present where necessary

Comment: EDIT:and on further review, there was one View which needed the using statement. Not sure why the project builds when there are errors in the views.

Comment: @dinotom views aren't compiled until runtime.